# How do I convert a method in an Entity Framework model into an Expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

So my specific example is as follows: I have a model called Asset

```
public class Asset
{
    public Asset()
    {
        Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }    

    public Transaction CurrentTransaction => Transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.Created).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And what I want to do is convert the CurrentTransaction() method into something that will run faster and not need to be pulled into memory (as in compile to SQL) when I need to get a list of all assets and the current transaction for each.

I really know nothing of expressions or functions and I feel like this is something that has been done many times, I just cant seems to find the right words to search.

Comment: Since `Asset.Transactions` is a navigation-property, accessing it will always cause EF to load the entire set into memory (`IQueryable<T>` navigation properties are not supported) and further calls (like `OrderByDescending()`) will be processed by Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: Can you suggest anything that might make my data structure respond faster?  Basically I want to pull a table of all assets (possibly 10's of thousands) and the latest transaction for each. So doing a select with CurrentTransaction as a property will make several thousand calls to the database.

Comment: Try to project into another type from your EF context. Something like: `context.Assets.Select(x => new { Asset = x, CurrentTransaction = x.Transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.Created).FirstOrDefault() });` (you may want to replace `new { ... }` with `new YourResultType { ... }` instead)